# Apple gamecenter available test returns YES on iphone 3g

Tags: iphone, gamekit

I'm making a game with gamecenter support. I want to diable a button for iPhone 3g or older devices. But my 3g test device says, that gamecenter is available and the matchmaking view show up. The user will never get authenticated. I use the snippet from apple to check, if gamecenter is available. It should return NO on devices older than 3gs

```
-(BOOL)isGameCenterAvailable {
// check for presence of GKLocalPlayer API
Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"));

// check if the device is running iOS 4.1 or later
NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.1";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
BOOL osVersionSupported = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer 
                                       options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);

return (gcClass && osVersionSupported); }
```

Does anyone do it better than apple?

Comment: iPhone 3G can run iOS 4.1 - maybe check what version of the OS is on your phone?

Comment: There is 4.2.1 on my 3g. just checking the OS version is not enough.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. GameCenter is in 4.2.1, and your 3G has that version installed. Isn't the code working correctly then?

Comment: No because the GameCenter is disabled on the 3g. Its ambivalent that the test of GameCenter availability says yes but you cant use it.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that GameCenter doesn't work on the 3G. Apple's docs cover this case too - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, there is more to detecting Game Center support than just checking for the existence of the API. According to [Optionally Supporting Game Center In Your Game](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW5), in addition to checking for the APIs you'll also need to authenticate the player:

> iOS 4.1 may be installed on some
>   devices that do not support Game
>   Center. On those devices, the
>   isGameCenterAPIAvailable function
>   defined Listing 1-1 still returns YES.
>   The next step in confirming whether
>   Game Center may be used on the device
>   is to attempt to authenticate the
>   local player; on devices that do not
>   support game center, your game
>   receives a GKErrorNotSupported error.